# How to find the limit of this hard sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

How to find this limits
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{n^2-(i-1)^2}{n\left\{[2n(a+b)]^2+[a(2i-1)]^2\right\}}$$
Where $a$ and $b$  are real positive constants.

My friend asked this question,but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: What is known about $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @GiovanniDeGaetano Both are constant

Comment: @GiovanniDeGaetano my fault.They are all real positive constants.

Comment: What I wrote in the comment is very probably wrong, I misread your sum.

Comment: The largest term in the sum is for $i = 1$, and then we have $\frac{n}{[2n(a+b)]^2 + [a\cdot 1]^2} < \frac{1}{4(a+b)^2n}$, so each sum is between $0$ and $\frac{1}{4(a+b)^2}$.

Comment: I think Reimann sum should do it.

Comment: @DanielFischer could you please show me more details about it,thank you!

Comment: @DanielFischer I didn't understand the each sum you said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n \to \infty}\,\,\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{n^{2} - \pars{i - 1}^{2} \over
n\braces{\bracks{2n\pars{a + b}}^{\,2} + \bracks{a\pars{2i - 1}}^{\,2}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\braces{{1 \over 4na^{2}}
\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{4n^{2} - \bracks{\pars{2i - 1} - 1}^{\,2} \over
\xi_{n}^{\,2} + \pars{2i - 1}^{2}}}\quad
\mbox{where}\quad\xi_{n} \equiv 2\pars{1 + {b \over a}}n\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
Then,
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n \to \infty}\,\,\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{n^{2} - \pars{i - 1}^{2} \over
n\braces{\bracks{2n\pars{a + b}}^{\,2} + \bracks{a\pars{2i - 1}}^{\,2}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\braces{{1 \over 4na^{2}}
\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{\xi_{n}^{2} + 4n^{2} - \xi_{n}^{2} - \pars{2i - 1}^{2} -2\pars{2i - 1} - 1 \over
\pars{2i - 1}^{2} + \xi_{n}^{\,2}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\braces{{\xi_{n}^{2} + 4n^{2} - 1 \over 4na^{2}}\
\underbrace{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{1 \over \pars{2i - 1}^{2} + \xi_{n}^{\,2}}}
_{\ds{\equiv\ J_{1}}}\ -\ {1 \over 4a^{2}} -
{1 \over 2na^{2}}\
\underbrace{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{2i - 1 \over\pars{2i - 1}^{2} + \xi_{n}^{\,2}}}
_{\ds{\equiv\ J_{2}}}}
\end{align}

---

\begin{equation}
\mbox{Note that}\quad
J_{1} = {1 \over \xi_{n}}\,\Im\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over 2k - 1 - \xi_{n}\ic}
\quad\mbox{and}\quad
J_{2} = \Re\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over 2k - 1 - \xi_{n}\ic}\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{equation}

---

Therefore,
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over 2k - 1 - \xi_{n}\ic} & =
{1 \over 2}\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}{1 \over k + 1/2 - \xi_{n}\ic/2} =
{1 \over 2}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over k + 1/2 - \xi_{n}\ic/2} -
{1 \over k + n + 1/2 - \xi_{n}\ic/2}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\bracks{\Psi\pars{{1 \over 2} + {2n - \xi_{n}\ic \over 2}} -
\Psi\pars{{1 \over 2} - {\xi_{n}\ic \over 2}}}\quad
\pars{~\Psi:\ Digamma\ Function~}
\end{align}

---

$$
\mbox{Note that}\quad
\Psi\pars{{1 \over 2} + z} \sim
\ln\pars{z} + {1 \over 24z^{2}} - {7 \over 960z^{4}}\quad\mbox{as}\quad
\verts{z} \to \infty 
$$

---

Then, as $\ds{n \to \infty}$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over 2k - 1 - \xi_{n}\ic}
\\[5mm] \sim &\
\bracks{{1 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{n - {\xi_{n} \over 2}\,\ic} +
{1 \over 48}\,{1 \over \pars{n - \xi_{n}\ic/2}^{2}}} -
\bracks{{1 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{-\,{\xi_{n} \over 2}\,\ic} +
{1 \over 48}\,{1 \over \pars{-\xi_{n}\ic/2}^{2}}}
\\[5mm] \sim &\
{1 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{{2n \over \xi_{n}}\,\ic - 1} =
{1 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{-1 + {a \over a + b}\,\ic} =
{1 \over 4}\ln\pars{1 + \bracks{a \over a + b}^{2}} -
{1 \over 2}\,\arctan\pars{a \over a + b}\ic
\end{align}

---

As $\ds{n \to \infty}$,
$$
J_{1} \sim -\,{1 \over 2\xi_{n}}\arctan\pars{a \over a + b}\,,\qquad
J_{2} \sim {1 \over 4}\ln\pars{1 + \bracks{a \over a + b}^{2}}
$$

---

The coveted limit is given by
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n \to \infty}\,\,\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{n^{2} - \pars{i - 1}^{2} \over
n\braces{\bracks{2n\pars{a + b}}^{\,2} + \bracks{a\pars{2i - 1}}^{\,2}}}
\\[5mm] = &
\lim_{n \to \infty}\braces{{\xi_{n}^{2} + 4n^{2} - 1 \over 4na^{2}}\bracks{-\,{1 \over 2\xi_{n}}\arctan\pars{a \over a + b}}} - {1 \over 4a^{2}}
\\[5mm] = & \bbx{\ds{%
-\,{2a^{2} + 2ab + b^{2} \over 4a^{3}\pars{a + b}}\,\arctan\pars{a \over a + b} -
{1 \over 4a^{2}}}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing something, this is a simple [Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum). Just write $$\lim_{n\to\infty}~\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{n^2-(i-1)^2}{n\left\{[2n(a+b)]^2+[a(2i-1)]^2\right\}}~=~\lim_{n\to\infty}~\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{n^2-i^2}{n\left\{[2n(a+b)]^2+[a(2i)]^2\right\}},$$ since, as $n\to\infty,~$ the influence of the $-1$ on the value of the series tends to $0,~$ so its presence or absence is irrelevant. $($Even if it would have been $\pm1,000,~$ or even $\pm1,000,000,~$ it still would not have made any difference$).~$ Now drag the $\dfrac1n$ outside the series, since its value doesn't depend on the iterator *i*, and simplify the remaining fraction by dividing both its numerator and denominator by $n^2.~$ We then have $S=\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{1-x^2}{4(a+b)^2~+~4a^2x^2}~dx,~$ whose evaluation is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I post this as an answer when it is only a lower bound, but I do not have enough reputation to comment.

First note that, after the swap $i \to n-i+1$ the sum is
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i(2n-i)}{4n^2(a+b)^2+a^2(2n+1-2i)^2}
$$

By AM-GM, the $n$-th term is greater than or equal to
\begin{align*}
\left (\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{i(2n-i)}{4n^2(a+b)^2+a^2(2n+1-2i)^2} \right )^{1/n} &= \left [\frac{(2n)!}{2} \right ]^{1/n} \left (\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{4n^2(a+b)^2+a^2(2n+1-2i)^2} \right )^{1/n} \\ &\geq \left [\frac{(2n)!}{2} \right ]^{1/n} \left (\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{4n^2[(a+b)^2+a^2]} \right )^{1/n} \\ &= \left [\frac{(2n)!}{2} \right ]^{1/n} \frac{1}{4n^2[(a+b)^2+a^2]}
\end{align*}
which tends to
$$
\frac{1}{e^2[(a+b)^2+a^2]}
$$
unless I was wrong using Stirling.

So, taking in account Daniel Fischer's useful comment, one should have that your limit (if it exists) is between
$$
\frac{1}{e^2[(a+b)^2+a^2]} \text{ and } \frac{1}{4(a+b)^2}.
$$

Comment: (+1) for conveying the idea of your (partial) solution clearly.